# Win32 api call via C# fails!

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pinvoke

I have a C++ function exported as api like this:

```
#define WIN322_API __declspec(dllexport)
WIN322_API char* Test(LPSTR str);
WIN322_API char* Test(LPSTR str)
{
 return "hello";
}
```

the function is exported as API correctly by the .DEF file, cause i can see it in Dependency Walker tool.
Now i have a C# tester program:

```
[DllImport("c:\\win322.dll")]

public static extern string Test([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String str);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string _str = "0221";
Test(_str); // runtime error here!

}
```

on calling the Test() method i get the error:

"A call to PInvoke function 'MyClient!MyClient.Form1::Test' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature."

i tried many other data types and marshalings, but got nothing!
plz help me!

Comment: Maybe you need to set the return type to something along the lines of char[]/IntPtr? Im no P/Invoke expert so i dont really know.

Comment: The P/Invoke Signature toolkit translates your C code into an `IntPtr` return type.

Comment: my return value doesn't have problem. it returns the string correctly if i remove the input parameter. the input parameter is the error point!

Comment: This question has been asked 100's of times. Please search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the correct calling convention. Your DLL may use Cdecl, while C# defaults to StdCall. It's better to always explicitly define the calling convention.

Especially when using Windows functions which exist in an ANSI and wide char version (those with an A or W prefix), explicitly specify the CharSet so the correct version is used.

When the function returns a value, explictly marshal the return value. Otherwise, the compiler chooses a default, which may be wrong. **I suspect this is (also) the problem here.**

So change to this, for example:

```
[DllImport("c:\\win322.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string Test([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String str);
```

Comment: thanks Daniel. the '__stdcall' convention i put on my C++ function workedc and caused that i can send input parameters to it. but i still face some new problems. i'll try what u said too. tnx

Comment: @user434186 The default setting of the Visual Studio projects is to use Cdecl unless otherwise specified. So you could also remove the __stdcall part in your C++ function and specify Cdecl in the P/Invoke code.

Answer (score 5):

It is caused by a mismatch on the calling convention, the default for [DllImport] is Stdcall but the C compiler's default is Cdecl.  Use the CallingConvention property in the declaration.

That's not the only problem though, this code will crash on Vista and Win7.  Returning a string from a C function is quite troublesome, there's a memory management problem.  It isn't clear who is responsible for freeing the string buffer.  You are returning a literal now but that's going to stop being useful pretty soon.  Next stop is using malloc() for the return string with the intent for the caller to call free().  That's not going to work, the pinvoke marshaller cannot call it since it doesn't know what heap the C code is using.

It will call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem().  That's wrong, the string wasn't allocated by CoTaskMemAlloc().  That goes unnoticed on XP and earlier, other than the very hard to diagnose memory leak this causes.  And goes kaboom on Vista and Win7, they have a much more stricter memory manager.

You need to rewrite the C function like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 
void __stdcall Test(const char* input, char* output, int outLen);
```

Now the caller supplies the buffer, through the *output* argument, there's no longer a guess who owns the memory.  You use StringBuilder in the C# declaration.

```
[DllImport("foo.dll")]
private static extern void Test(string input, StringBuilder output, int outLen);
...
    var sb = new StringBuilder(666);
    test("bar", sb, sb.Capacity);
    string result = sb.ToString();
```

Be careful to use the *outLen* argument in your C code so that you can be sure not to overflow the buffer.  That corrupts the garbage collected heap, crashing the app with a Fatal Execution Engine Error.

Comment: +1 for covering calling conventions *and* the pitfalls of returning `char *`.

Comment: Additionally, there is no direct way for the managed code to call free() on memory that has been allocated via malloc() (or at least I haven't found it). The only way is by having an additional DLL export in your C/C++ app which calls free() on the given handle.

Comment: Yup.  It does actually work if you use CoTaskMemAlloc() in the C code.

Answer (score 2):

Change your macro definition to

```
#define WIN322_API __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
```

As an alternative, use `CallingConvention.Cdecl` when importing.

Read, for example, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/calling_conventions_demystified.aspx) for more info on calling conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning LPSTR, not char*. You might also need to specify stdcall calling convention, which is default in .NET, but I'm not sure about your unmanaged project.

Comment: it returns the string correctly if i remove the input parameter. the input parameter is the error point!

Comment: Then it must be the calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

Use Unmanagedtype.LPTStr for the input. Notice the additional T

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String str  // your current code
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] String str // try this code
```

Comment: i tried that, and i saw no changes. i think there is a basic and fundamental mistake. cause i tried many other data types as input parameter, but got the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Pass a StringBuilder from .Net as a parameter rather than returning a string  (in this case it will be like an out parameter)

Comment: That is if you have are able to make changes to the DLL you are trying to call...